# Google Cloud Speech API for UWP application

Tags: uwp, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to develop a Speech to Text UWP application (Universal Window Platform) which get voice from microphone and steam to Google Cloud Speech Service.
But it seems that Google cloud Speech API has not supported UWP application.

The error below occurred when I install client library to my project using Nuget:

> Install-Package : Package Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 1.0.1 is not
>   compatible with uap10.0.10240 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) / win10-x86.
>   Package  Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 1.0.1 supports:
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>     - netstandard1.5 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5)

How can I apply Google Cloud Speech API for my UWP application ?

Comment: Set the UWP’s min target OS version to 16299 (currently you set it as 10240)

Comment: thank you for your help, but this problem still occur even I changed min target OS version to 16299.

Comment: Look Closer @ the message. It says it is not supported for UAP At all. It only support .NetFramework and .netstandard1.5. Since you can reference a .netstandard class library from UWP app, Create a new .netstandard project in your solution, add the package there, and use the functionality from your UWP app. Note that .netstandard does not support all UWP api's so make sure it fits your requirements.