# Unity3D: The type 'ServiceEndpoint' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Api.Gax.Grpc'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-speech-api

I was able to install Google Speech API in my Unity3D project. I am building on UWP platform (developing for Hololens)

```
 private static async Task<object> StreamingRecognizeAsync(string filePath)
    {
        var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
        var streamingCall = speech.StreamingRecognize();
        // Write the initial request with the config.
        await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
            new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
            {
                StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
                {
                    Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                    {
                        Encoding =
                        RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                        SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                        LanguageCode = "en",
                    },
                    InterimResults = true,
                }
            });
        return null;
    }
```

When I added this snippet mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-recognize-csharp

it throws me an error `The type 'ServiceEndpoint' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Api.Gax.Grpc, Version=2.9.0.0, Culture=neutral'.`

[image]

I clicked on `AddReference`, still it doesn't change anything. What do I do? I am encountering this type of problem for the first time.

Comment: Have you added the relevant DLL to your Unity project?

Comment: @Draco18s not yet! How can I get those?

Comment: Google has nuget and github repositories of everything.

Comment: @Draco18s I just checked, its already installed. In my Nuget Manager console, it shows Google Speech has already installed. It is located in packages folder in root directory

Comment: @Draco18s Do you think it can be because I'm using UWP platform? 
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/983
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031933/google-cloud-speech-api-for-uwp-application I just came across these

Comment: To be clear, we don't support Unity with the Google Cloud Client Libraries. While you *may* be able to get it to work - and if you do, I'm happy for you - we won't be able to support you for problems like this, I'm afraid :(

Comment: @JonSkeet that means it's possible? what way would you recommend to use?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using it. I don't know whether it's possible. I don't know it to be *im*possible, but that's not the same thing.